# Center cursor click position in Google maps javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a cursor on google maps pretty easy:

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor: 'url(images/pointcursor.png), auto'});
```

The problem is it uses the default top left click position for the cursor. I have pretty much created crosshairs, so I would like the click position to be in the center.

How do I specify this?

Comment: According to the docs _"This property uses the css cursor attribute to change the icon"_  So you should be able to apply any relevant CSS to that property, not just the URL, which could align it?  Alternatively could you just do `draggableCursor: 'crosshair, auto'`

Comment: what do you really want? i don't understand what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @duncan, css cursor style, I just had to add the x y offset after the url like this:

map.setOptions({draggableCursor: 'url(images/pointcursor.png) **8 8**, auto'});